# How to apply a single section across multiple columns in Business Intelligence

Tags: formatting, business-intelligence, business-objects

I do a lot of reporting out of our Electronic Health Record using a Business Objects product, and one thing I run into frequently is records for which most of the columns are the same, but a few may have multiple different values.

For instance, a report I'm working on has 8 columns, mostly static information about the patient/encounter, some lab values, and a column for the consulting physician.  All the columns will have only a single value per patient/encounter, except for consulting physician which may have multiple.  I'd like to somehow set the table to show only a single row for the data that is unchanged, so they don't end up seeing the FIN, MRN, and lab values over and over.

However, as far as I've been able to tell with my fiddling around, I can only apply a section or break to a single column.  Creating multiple sections or breaks nests them.  Does anybody know of a way to treat multiple columns as sort of a composite section?

edit:  I did try pulling the consulting physician column out into its own table and then setting the room number as a section, but it still caused repeated rows of the other data for any that had multiple consultings.

Additional edit: As requested here's a mockup of approximately what I'd like to see.  This is mostly how it looks already when I tell BO to use the room number (the number in blue, top left of each row) as a section, however in the case of the third room, it would repeat the information in the first 5 columns for each consulting listed.

[image]

Comment: What do you want it to look like when there are multiples?

Comment: @Joe added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do it, but putting breaks on each column is what I would do.

So, starting from "FIN" and working to "Attending", add a break on each column.  It will add a summary row for each, so it will look like:
[image]

Then select the summary rows, right-click, and Delete:
[image]

Comment: Wow, it didn't even occur to me that I could safely delete that summary row.  Works like a champ.  Thanks!